# get kotlin error: Type argument is not within its bounds

Tags: kotlin, generics

I get error of Type argument is not within its bounds, supposing I have a class Bound

```
class Bound<T : RawType?>
```

and I tried to initialize Bound in kotlin but I got error like `Type argument is not within its bounds`
This is the raw type java code

```
Bound bound = new Bound();
```

Any suggestion how to translate this piece of code to kotlin?

Comment: As far I as know, [Kotlin does not support raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46828680/how-to-declare-raw-types-in-kotlin). And you should avoid raw types in Java if at all possible.

Comment: Ignore the rawtype, is it possible to initialize a bounded type?

Comment: Of course: `var bound = Bound<SomeType>()`, where `SomeType` is a subtype of `RawType` (directly or indirectly, or even `RawType` itself).

Comment: Do I need to create another subclass SomeType? or I could write something like 
var bound = Bound<out RawType>()? Thanks

Comment: If you don't know the specific type, use a "wildcard": `var bound: Bound<*> = Bound()`. Unfortunately, that seems to require making the type explicit.

Comment: But you could just do `var bound = Bound<RawType?>()`, which I believe is functionally the same as using `<*>` as in my previous comment.

Comment: RawType is a class name. if I rename it to MyType then I have 
class Bound<T : MyType?>

Comment: In which case you could do `var bound = Bound<MyType?>()` or something similar. I'm not sure I understand where the confusion is?

Comment: The confusion is I still want to pass a subtype explicitly to the type parameter of Bound. syntax similar to Bound<T:MyType> or Bound<out MyType>. I know this syntax is not correct, just wonder if there is any syntax for passing the subtype when initializing

Comment: But [that's what one of my previous comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73145450/get-kotlin-error-type-argument-is-not-within-its-bounds?noredirect=1#comment129185842_73145450) shows. Kotlin's generics work very similarly to Java's, except Java doesn't have declaration-site variance (i.e., the `class Bound<out MyType>` syntax in Kotlin). And `Bound<T : MyType>` is not the same as `Bound<out MyType>`. The former bounds `T` by `MyType`, the latter makes the class strictly a producer of `MyType`.

Comment: It sounds like `class Bound<T : MyType>` is exactly what you want. That allows for `T` to be `MyType` or **any** subtype of `MyType` when you use the class.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. supposing I have class Bound<T : MyType>, when initializing it , I still need to specify the type T. `val bound = Bound<MyType>()` is that correct? if I do `val bound = Bound()` it will give me error `Not enough information to infer type variable T`

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And if you had `class OtherType : MyType` then you could use `val bound = Bound<OtherType>()`. Also, if it was `class Bound<T : MyType>(val value: T)` then you could just have e.g., `val bound = Bound(OtherType())` and `T` would be _inferred_ as `OtherType`.